# Power supply raspberry pi 3 with AA batteries

Tags: power-supply

I want to know if it is possible to supply power to raspberry pi 3 with AA batteries.

Some electronic boards like Arduinos contains a voltage regulator. The Vin voltage input can be greater than 5V.

But i don't know if raspberries devices contains a regulator. Do they need exactly 5V ?

Thanks

Comment: At some point in this folly, you may wonder **how long** my RPi will run from AA batteries. When you reach that point, there are [some calculations](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/117533/83790) that may help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, can be done with a voltage converter.

I use 6x AA NiMH Eneloop Pro batteries which give about 7.2 volts along with a voltage/buck converter to step the voltage down to 5 volts.

Comment: And how many minutes does it run?

Comment: This isn't "useful" IMO.

Answer (score 1):

The maximum input voltage is 5.25v and a standard aa battery is only rated to supply 50ma of current so running a pi from aa batteries is not really feasible

Comment: the term is AA, not aa

Answer (score 1):

There are many things wrong with this approach.

AA batteries are not capable of supplying sufficient current; NiMh cells would be marginal.

The Pi has no regulator and operates over a narrow voltage range.