# Can AA batteries have voltage or current spikes?

Tags: gpio, battery, current

I'm a noob in raspberry pi and in engineering in general. I had an idea for a project but it requires it to be somewhat portable so I need to power the raspberry somehow. I read [this article](https://thepihut.com/blogs/raspberry-pi-tutorials/how-do-i-power-my-raspberry-pi#:%7E:text=A%20more%20technical%20(and%20of,over%2Dvoltage%20or%20current%20spikes.)) Where it says that it's possible but the rpi might be fried due to current spikes. I plan on powering it with AA batteries so do these have voltage or current spikes?

I also read on ups Hats that regulate the voltage and current but it's unavailable in my country

Thanks in advance

Comment: There is no such thing as a current spike. Having said that it is not feasible to power a Pi with AA cells.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Batteries do not create voltage & current spikes any more than any other power source - no worries there. Your worry will be figuring how many batteries you need - how much **energy** you need really since it's a product of power and time.

It's my opinion that powering an RPi from small batteries is rarely practical, but I don't know what your project is, so I can't say it won't work. If you're interested in making some rather simple calculations to learn how many batteries you'll need for a time period, [this answer may help you](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/117533/83790).